# Supertrait as return traitobject doesn't have a known size at compile time

Tags: rust, traits, trait-objects

I am working with the [DHT11 library](https://docs.rs/dht11/latest/dht11/struct.Dht11.html) where the argument `gpio`, based on the [esp32 implementation](https://esp-rs.github.io/esp-idf-svc/esp_idf_hal/gpio/struct.Pins.html), for new must implement `InputPin` and `OutputPin`.
So I created a function that returns a traitobject of a supertrait of those two traits. But when I want to dereference it to actually call `new`, I get the error `doesn't have a size known at compile-time`.

This is the supertrait I made from the above mentioned traits:

```
trait InputOutputPin: InputPin<Error = EspError> + OutputPin<Error = EspError> {}
impl<T: InputPin<Error = EspError> + OutputPin<Error = EspError>> InputOutputPin for T {}
```

This is the function that creates an gpio based on which pin number is given:

```
    fn get_gpio(pin: &u8) -> Result<&dyn InputOutputPin, &'static str>{
        match pin {
            33 => Ok(&Peripherals::take().unwrap().pins.gpio33.into_input_output().unwrap()),
            32 => Ok(&Peripherals::take().unwrap().pins.gpio32.into_input_output().unwrap()),
            27 => Ok(&Peripherals::take().unwrap().pins.gpio27.into_input_output().unwrap()),
            26 => Ok(&Peripherals::take().unwrap().pins.gpio26.into_input_output().unwrap()),
            25 => Ok(&Peripherals::take().unwrap().pins.gpio25.into_input_output().unwrap()),
            _ => Err("Pin not configurable for dht")
        }
    }
```

And this is how I assign the result from the function:

```
let gpio = Self::get_gpio(pin).unwrap();
let dht = Dht11::new(*gpio);
```

All I want to do is create a DHT11 object based on what pin number was chosen, but [the esp32 library](https://esp-rs.github.io/esp-idf-svc/esp_idf_hal/gpio/struct.Gpio1.html) implements every gpio as its own struct by using a [makro](https://esp-rs.github.io/esp-idf-svc/src/esp_idf_hal/gpio.rs.html#1463).
What am I missing or is there a obvious, much better way of doing it.

Comment: As this seems to go stale, I`ll add my workaround for now. 
I combined the creation of the dht11 object with the pin selection in one function. This is not clean and creates redundancy, but this eliminated the need for the supertrait. I am open to better suggestions:
For reference: [This commit](https://github.com/elheck/plantrs/commit/8b73c116350e42ed20b111dffd1a30d15844fece)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ESP32 HAL has a [degrade](https://esp-rs.github.io/esp-idf-svc/esp_idf_hal/gpio/struct.Gpio0.html#method.degrade) method for GPIO pins which erases the pin-specific typing so you don't need to use your dyn supertrait.

The modified code would like more like this:

```
fn get_gpio(pin: &u8) -> Result<GpioPin<InputOutput>, &'static str>{
        match pin {
            33 => Ok(&Peripherals::take().unwrap().pins.gpio33.into_input_output().unwrap().degrade()),
            32 => Ok(&Peripherals::take().unwrap().pins.gpio32.into_input_output().unwrap().degrade()),
            27 => Ok(&Peripherals::take().unwrap().pins.gpio27.into_input_output().unwrap().degrade()),
            26 => Ok(&Peripherals::take().unwrap().pins.gpio26.into_input_output().unwrap().degrade()),
            25 => Ok(&Peripherals::take().unwrap().pins.gpio25.into_input_output().unwrap().degrade()),
            _ => Err("Pin not configurable for dht")
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Danila's answer is correct for the general case of working with supertraits, however I think this answer is better suited for the OP's specific situation.

Comment: Ok I hadn't seen the degrade method. This solves my problem most adequately. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use Box for this. Example:

```rust
impl InputOutputPin for Box<dyn InputOutputPin> {}
```

and change the function from

```rust
 fn get_gpio(pin: &u8) -> Result<&dyn InputOutputPin, &'static str> {..}
```

to

```rust
fn get_gpio(pin: &u8) -> Result<Box<dyn InputOutputPin>, &'static str> {...}
```

Then this will work without problems:

```rust
let gpio = Self::get_gpio(pin).unwrap();
let dht = Dht11::new(*gpio);
```

Comment: The ESP32 is a microcontroller, and there's a good chance the OP (or future askers of questions like this) is working in a no_std environment without an allocator. Is there an alternative solution that doesn't involve a Box?

Comment: @effect, you can do it like this ```impl InputOutputPin for &dyn InputOutputPin {} ``` or ```impl InputOutputPin for &mut dyn InputOutputPin {} ```

Comment: Won't they still have the issue of not being able to return an `&dyn InputOutputPin` because the size isn't known at compile time? I don't see how those impl changes removes the need for a Box.

Comment: @effect, the problem with the size occurs only when dereferencing ```let dht = Dht11::new(*gpio);``` and this implementation allows you not to dereference, but to pass the link directly ```let dht = Dht11::new(gpio);``` where ```gpio``` has type ```&dyn InputOutputPin```